# Passing data from TableViewController to TableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, parameter-passing

I created a TableViewController and I'm displaying some data coming from an Array.
I had to create a TableViewCellController also, because i need to have a button for each row, which has to perform an action.

So, this is a part of my TableViewController:

```
struct person {
  var name:String
  var age:String
  var address:String
}
class myTableViewController: UITableViewController {
  var people = Array<person>()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var x = person(name: "Marco", age: "28", address: "street a")
    var y = person(name: "Pippo", age: "90", address: "street b")
    people.append(x)
    people.append(y)
  }

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> myTableViewCell {
    let CellId: String = "Cell"
    var cell: myTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CellId) as myTableViewCell
    cell.textLabel!.text = people[indexPath.row].name
    return cell
  }

}
```

The table is printed fine as you can see in the following picture:

[image: Table View Controller]

Now, i need to access the property address every time i press the button "Address" which you can see in the picture.
So i tried with the following code, inside class TableViewController:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> myTableViewCell {
  let CellId: String = "Cell"
  var cell: myTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CellId) as myTableViewCell
  cell.textLabel!.text = people[indexPath.row].name

  cell.buttonPlay?.tag = indexPath.row
  cell.buttonPlay?.addTarget(cell, action: "playActionX:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

  return cell
}
```

and, from TableViewCell i correctly receive the tag:

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

  func playActionX(sender:UIButton!) {
    println(sender.tag)
  }
```

Everything fine. But the problem is, i cannot send strings inside the tag and I don't know how to access the 'address' field from my TableViewController.

What solution could i use for that?
PS. I have tried to create an instance to the TableViewController class:

```
func playActionX(sender:UIButton!) {
  println(sender.tag)
  let instance:MyTableViewController = MyTableViewController()
  println(instance.getPeopleArray())
}
```

(getPeopleArray is just returning the array people)
but strangely the array i receive it's empty and i don't understand why.

Thanks for your support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `getPeopleArray` is empty because you are creating a new instance of MyTableViewController, not accessing the existing one.  But don't go that route.  Instead just change your target/action for the buttons to your view Controller, not the cell.  So change:

```
cell.buttonPlay?.addTarget(cell, action: "playActionX:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

to

```
cell.buttonPlay?.addTarget(self, action: "playActionX:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

and move the `playActionX:` function to the table view controller.  From there you can use the tag as an index into your people array.

Comment: I have just tried and it's working! Thanks!! I don't know how but when i tried before i was getting the following error" unrecognized selector sent to instance" and that is why i decided to move the function playActionX inside the TableViewCell class.
Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Since you set the `tag = indexPath.row`, you will be able to find the address the same way its done in `cellFoRowAtIndexPath`, that is:  `people[sender.tag].address`.

The reason you're finding the array empty in your attempt is that you've allocated a new one along with the new view controller.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But my array is not defined in TableViewCell, That is the problem. How can i access that from another class?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are assigning the button tags in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, you should be able to access the object in your people array with `people[sender.tag]` (called from inside `playActionX`).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i wasn't able to access the array people in that way because the array was defined in TableViewController class and not in the TableViewCell class